# single model or collection in backbone app and how to access it

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs

I am looking on the Addy Osmani's Todos mvc site on the [Backbone+RequireJS](https://github.com/addyosmani/todomvc/tree/gh-pages/dependency-examples/backbone_require/js) project. I am looking on the Todos collection since it is not a standart object. The Todos collection is instanciate only once and in the todos.js file since we don't need two Todos collection. Therefore Addy creates an instance in the todos.js file and returns it.

I am wondering if this is a good practice for such "singleton" objects. For example, assume I have a model and my ject needs only one instance of this model, should I return an instanciated model in the model.js file (in case I am working with RequireJS)? What should I do in such case when not working with RequireJS?

Another question is dealing with how I can get access to the model instance. In case I return an instance in the model.js file (using RequireJS), I only need to put the model.js in the dependencies list and I get the instance. But what if I am not working with RequireJS or if I decide not to return an instanciated model in the model.js? In this case, what are good practices to get access to the instance of the model?

Answer (score 0):

```
var myApp = {
    controllers : {},
    models : {},
    routers : {},
    instances : {}

};
```

The simplest way would be:

```
myApp.models.Model = (function() {

    /* Model initiation etc can go here, just return the model in the end*/
    var Model = new Backbone.Model.extend({
        /* bla bla*/
    });

    return Model;

})();

myApp.instances.modelInstance = (function() {
    return new myApp.models.Model with app specific data;
})();
```

if you're going to continue to use requirejs (**which you should cause its awesome**)

```
define(["deps1", "deps"], function(deps1, deps2) {

 var Model = new Backbone.Model.extend({
            /* bla bla*/
        });

        return Model;
});
```

and then define a new file ("modelInstance.js")

```
define(["Model"], function(Model) {


    return new Model with app specific data;
});
```

Comment: How do I access the model from other view? With or without RequireJS?

Comment: About your update, I am trying to understand if return an instance in RequireJS is a good practice? For example, you might want later reuse this model for other purposes and then you would not be able to use your code.

Comment: What I ment: I will appriciate example of how accessing the model from a view that I have with/without using RequireJS.

Comment: I was under the impression that your application only requires that model with specific data. If you want to re-use the model, declare it and then declare a new instance that uses that model. I updated my answer to reflect these changes.